# Karate Api : check if a phrase is available response object array

Tags: karate

I've a response

```
{ errors: [
       {
        code: 123,
        reason: "this is the cause for a random problem where the last part of this string is dynamically generated"
     }  ,
     {
        code: 234,
        reason: "Some other error for another random reason"
     }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now when I validate this response
I use following

```
...
...    
And match response.errors[*].reason contains "this is the cause"
```

This validation fails, because there is an equality check for `complete String` for every `reason` ,

I all I want is, to validate that inside the `errors` array, if there is any `error` object, which has a `reason` string type property, starting with `this is the cause` phrase.

I tried few wild cards but didn't work either, how to do it ?

Comment: you again provided invalid json. I'm complaining because my approach is to cut-and-paste and try things out. well, thanks :|

Comment: My bad, I still did not get whats wrong in JSON.. Sorry I was simplifying the example json for the question. Actual business response is very different. but problem was same

Comment: just take the response json you provided and paste it into a json validator and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex things like this, just switch to JS.

```
* def found = response.errors.find(x => x.reason.startsWith('this is the cause'))
* match found == { code: 123, reason: '#string' }
# you can also do
* if (found) karate.log('found')
```

Any questions :)

Comment: Thanks, I used first suggestion. With a small change in `found ==` , I changed  `code` to '#string',  same as `reason`  . As all I wanted was to check if any record exists.. Thanks again.